# Pub/Sub in Javascript explaination needed

Tags: javascript

im trying to understand the pub/sub design pattern with Pluralsight and there is a line of code that i don't understand.

there is `arguments` in each method of js that like array but it is not.
and in the pub method they use the arguments to iterate and invoke each callback and return those arguments that the method was sending.

it looks like this:

```
define("EventHandler", [], function () {

var cache = {};

return {

    pub: function(id)
    {
        var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 1);

        if (!cache[id])
            cache[id] = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < cache[id].length; i++) {

            cache[id][i].apply(null, args);

        }

    },

    sub:  function(id, callback)
    {
        if (!cache[id])
            cache[id] = [callback];
        else
            cache[id].push(callback);
    }

}});
```

the line that i dont understand is:

```
var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 1);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You know what [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) are and what [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does?

Comment: They should have use `var args =`[`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)`.call(arguments, 1)`

Comment: i know what they do but i cant understand the call function here.

Comment: It [calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the splice method on the arguments "array" with the argument `1`. Removing all values except for the id, and returning them as an array.

Comment: @Bergi that's a *convenient* way to do it, but leaking `arguments` out of a function messes up it's "optimizability" (if that's a word)

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, I know, and hope that engines will at some day recognize `slice` calls :-) Regardless, I wanted to focus on the fact that they better don't modify the `arguments` object…

Comment: @Bergi understood; sorry for the moment of pedanticism.